# Manipulating (read/write) data of a file from a program in non-binary mode

Tags: c, database, file-io

I am in the process of making a school database system for a project. The requirements prohibit me from using binary modes (i.e. "rb"). The problem though is that in one of the seven options, option 1, I'm required to load all the files, meaning that let's say if I were to use option 3 which adds a student record (student ID and student name) to the file, then when I load all the files once more in option 1, the program is meant to recognize the information already in the file. So, if I were to use option 3 one more time the program should prevent me from inputting the same student ID (as that is one of the project restrictions) when adding a new student record. As far as I know (which is not much but...), manipulating file data in binary mode makes this easier because you can manipulate blocks of data and such. I'm not entirely familiar with this and am hoping if anyone could suggest some functions which I could use. Actually, more specifically, from what I understand the advantage of binary mode is that it is easy to calculate the (offset?), so perhaps I'm required to be able to manipulate the offset in non-binary modes? If so, anyone people enlighten me.

Comment: I've a feeling [a few of these will be in order.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io)

Comment: I apologize, the question was not specific enough. It has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, it's a text file?

Then, you should never try to "update" the file. Just read it all (parsing it in the process), update the parsed data, and overwrite the file.

This can be done with the "create new, then delete old and rename new" method, which has the advantage of being able to do it without loading the whole file in memory (just read one record from the input file, update it when appropriate, and write it in the output stream, rinse, repeat).

```
struct Record { ... }
int ReadAndParseRecord(FILE*, struct Record*); /*Will contain calls to fgets(), fscanf()*/
void WriteRecord(FILE*, struct Record const *); /*Will contain calls to fputs(), fprintf()*/

void DoWorkOnOneRecord(struct Record *);

void DoWork(char const *filenameIn, char const *filenameOut)
{
    FILE* fileIn = fopen(filenameIn, "r");
    FILE* fileOut = fopen(filenameOut, "w");
    struct Record currentRecord;
    while(ReadAndParseRecord(fileIn, &currentRecord))
    {
        DoWorkOnOneRecord(&currentRecord);
        WriteRecord(fileOut, &currentRecord);
    }
    /*If there are any records to add, do it here*/
    /*...*/
    fclose(fileIn), fclose(fileOut);
}
```

And when you have to update the file, you DoWork() into a new file, then delete the old one and rename the new one (you can also have a backup of the old one, in which case change the sequence to "delete the backup, rename the old one, rename the new one").

Comment: I never thought about this kind of method. I don't understand why the ReadAndParseRecord function would have a return value of type int though. Could you please clarify why?

Comment: Because I'm an old geezer used to Visual Studio, so I can't use the C99 _Bool type instead. In short, it's supposed to return a boolean value, that would be false when it failed to read the next record (due to end of file, or error. Note that I didn't put any error handling in this sample code)